# How can i get information about Telegram channels without bot api?

Tags: telegram

It is necessary to regularly receive for the site the number of subscribers and avatars for the specified channel logins.
Is it possible to implement this?
On the official site I see only API for bots and API for developing applications based on Telegram.

Answer (score 0):

If there is no API, you're in trouble. Once I had a similiar problem and decided to.. parse HTML. And that ruined my personality.